# Enternal Analog Reference mode not compiling in Arduino + Intel Galileo Gen 2

Tags: arduino-galileo

I am trying to use external voltage reference in Intel Galileo gen 2 operating in Arduino mode.

So I created a setup code like this:

```
void setup() {
  // We'll send debugging information via the Serial monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);   

  // If you want to set the aref to something other than 5v
  analogReference(EXTERNAL); // use AREF for reference voltage
}
```

I selected the board as Intel Galileo Gen 2 in Tools option. When I compiled I am getting the following error:

```
LM35_temp_sensor.ino:21:19: error: 'EXTERNAL' was not declared in this scope
```

But when I change the board to Arduino Uno in Tools option, the program in compiling fine.

This means that Intel Galileo Gen 2 does not support external analog voltage reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an external analog reference on the Galileo.  If you look at the block diagram that is on the Galiley Arduino.cc page you can clearly see that the Aref pin goes nowhere:

[image]

So no, it won't support the EXTERNAL analog reference function.